# How to insert HTML datetime-local input into MYSQL table datetime column using php?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
include "session.php";
if(isset($_POST['permission'])) {
  $x = $_POST['x'];
  $reason = $_POST['reason'];
  $leaving = $_POST['leaving'];
  $returning = $_POST['returning'];



  $query = "INSERT INTO permissions (reason, leaving, returning, user, x) VALUES('$reason', '$leaving', '$returning', '$login_session', '$x')";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);// or die('Error querying database!');
  if ($result === false) { die(mysqli_error($db)); }
  echo 'Thanks for Posting! Your request will be addressed as soon as possible!';
}
```

What is wrong with this code? The leaving and returning columns are of type- DATETIME. is that causing a problem?

```
<form method="post" action="" class="forms">
        Type: <select name="x" required>
          <option value="0">Leave</option>
          <option value="1">Other</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="reason" placeholder="Reason" required><br>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="leaving"><br>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="returning"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Request Permission" name="permission">
      </form>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but if you want to insert the date to those fields, you can set their default values to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @mzcoxfde The above code is giving me a sql syntax error. i think the datetime-local type and datetime column type is causing that...

Comment: I have posted the answer. In case you still face any issues, then share the exact error and line number where you are getting it.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'returning, user, x) VALUES('gotcha gotcha gotcha gotcha ', '2017-04-06T12:00', '' at line 1...this is the error i am facing

Comment: Can you share the session.php?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: <?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'hostel');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,'',DB_DATABASE);
   session_start();
   
   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   
   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select enrno from students where enrno = '$user_check' ");
   
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   
   $login_session = $row['enrno'];
   
   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:index.php");
   }
?>

Comment: @tadman how do i accomplish that?

Comment: I put a bunch of links in there. Follow those and you'll have all the information you'll need.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi i have commented the session.php code...but i highly doubt that the problem has anything to do with it...

Comment: I have tested this code and works perfectly fine if I define the $login_session manually. To debug the exact error, try to run your code by removing $login_session value from the INSERT query. I am assuming that you have already fixed you DB based on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want, follow the below steps.

1. Instead of having Fields type as "DATETIME" in the DB, have them simple VARCHAR with the length of around 99 in order to store full format date and time easily.
2. Input Type "datetime-local" is actually not required. Simply use Input Type "date" is OK as you are not capturing the Time.

Once you are ready with the above fixes, amend your PHP code as below. If you want, you can simply copy/paste it as well.

```
<?php
    include "session.php";

    if(isset($_POST['permission'])) {
        $x = $_POST['x'];
        $reason = $_POST['reason'];
        $leaving = $_POST['leaving'];
        $returning = $_POST['returning'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO permissions (reason, leaving, returning, user, x) VALUES('$reason', '$leaving', '$returning', '$login_session', '$x')";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);// or die('Error querying database!');

        if ($result === false) {
            die(mysqli_error($db));
        }

        echo 'Thanks for Posting! Your request will be addressed as soon as possible!';
    }
?>
```

Now to retrieve this date value in your required format, use the below code.

```
$fetched_date = "04-09-2017" //Assuming that this Sunday, April 9, 2017 is the fetched date and stored in "04-09-2017"
```

Now to convert it to Sunday, April 9, 2017 simply follow the below steps.

```
$fetched_date_uf = date_create($fetched_date);
$fetched_date_formatted = date_format($fetched_date_uf, 'l, F d, Y');

echo $fetched_date_formatted; //Sunday, April 9, 2017
```

Refer to [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for PHP Date Time Formats.

Comment: This is not the answer of what he has asked.